# How to make pull down activity layout to refresh in android?

Tags: java, android-studio, swiperefreshlayout, pull-to-refresh

I have seen in many application that pulling down to refresh the whole layout. How can I make that type of pull down to refresh. I am new in android development. I want to learn about this.

As for example I am showing some images
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sjilq.png)

Update
Here is that example, how I want to refresh the layout after pull down the layout

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyGc4.gif)

Answer (score 2):

Make your activity's parent layout as  `androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout`
You can learn more at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-create-a-swipe-refresh-layout-in-android-using-kotlin

Comment: no, I have update my question you can see it, how I want it to be look like, @Abdullah Javed if possible show me some example

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this type of layout

https://developer.android.com/training/swipe/add-swipe-interface

Comment: no I had tried that material swipRefreshLayout, but I don't want that @kboskin I have update my question you can see it. If possible show me some example